# How do i put together the bootloader and the OS in Assembly made OS?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader

recently i have been trying to create a small operating system in assembly, but since it was a bootloader, i quickly noticed that only 512 bytes weren't enough for my project. So i read that to get around this problem i had to make a bootloader that would load the OS, mitigating the 512 bytes bootloader restriction. So i created the bootloader. And now i have both the bootlaoder and the os in .BIN format. But the problem is that i don't know how to put them together on a hard disc or on a CD.

I have tried to use disc burning tools to make a .ISO file out of it, but what i got was just a blinking dash when booting it. Here is the short code i used for the first bootloader: (I am using FASM)

```
ORG 0x7C00       

start:
    xor ax, ax      ; Clear ax register
    mov ss, ax      ; Set stack segment to 0
    mov sp, 0x7C00  ; Set stack pointer to boot sector address

    ; Load the second-stage bootloader
    mov ah, 0x02    ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al, 1       ; Number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0       ; Cylinder number
    mov dh, 0       ; Head number
    mov dl, 0x80    ; Drive number
    mov bx, 0x1000  ; Address to load the second-stage bootloader
    mov es, bx      ; Set es register to the segment of the destination address
    xor bx, bx      ; Offset in es:bx set to 0

    int 0x13        ; BIOS Interrupt to read HD

    ; Jump to the loaded program (OS)
    jmp 0x1000:0000

    ; Loop indefinitely
    cli             ; Disable interrupts
    hlt             ; Halt the CPU

times 510-($-$$) db 0  ; Fill with zeroes
dw 0xAA55              ; Boot signature
```

Thanks in advance for every response

Comment: Just appending the two bin files should work for a hard disk, usb drive or floppy. For iso you need to author an image. Also, remove the `mov dl, 0x80` as the BIOS already passes the correct value for you which might not be `0x80`. You can remove the `cli`/`hlt` as well since the `jmp` has no chance of returning.

Comment: Thanks! i created a single .BIN file out of the bootloader and the OS, now i will try to put them on my hard disk and try it on real hardware